# How do I access my application's state (classes, properties, etc.) upon a callback from CFStream?

Tags: iphone, background, voip

I'm writing an iPhone app that involves handling network events from a server over a VoIP socket in the background. I've successfully set up the socket, the background service info in the .plist, and the appropriate streams, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do anything useful in my callback. I don't know how to access the rest of my application's state from within the callback function. Here is where I set up the connections in the AppDelegate:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CFReadStreamRef readStream; 
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFHostRef host = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)@"irc.freenode.net");
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, 6667, &readStream, &writeStream);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);

    CFStreamClientContext myContext = {
        0,
        viewController,
        (void *(*)(void *info))CFRetain,
        (void (*)(void *info))CFRelease,
        (CFStringRef (*)(void *info))CFCopyDescription
    };

    CFOptionFlags registeredEvents = kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable |
    kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered;

    if(CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, registeredEvents, clientCB, &myContext)) {
        CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    }

    if (!CFReadStreamOpen(readStream)) {
        NSLog(@"Read stream could not be opened");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully opened read stream");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And here is the callback function for CFStream events, where I'm having my issues:

```
void clientCB(CFReadStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType event, void* myPtr) {
    switch(event) {
        case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:{
            UInt8 buf[32];
            CFIndex bytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(stream, buf, 32);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                NSLog(@"Readstream Not Empty %i", buf[0]);//dummy debug marker
            }
            //I WANT TO ACCESS CLASSES, PROPERTIES, FUNCTIONS, ETC. ABOUT THE REST OF MY PROGRAM HERE (E.G. GET A WORKING POINTER BACK TO THE MAIN APPDELEGATE).
        break;
    }
    case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
    case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

These two functions are both defined in the same AppDelegate class. I've tried passing pointers via the CFStreamClientContext struct: `VoIP_TestViewController* testViewController = context->info;`, I've tried to access the main appDelegate via: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, and I've tried the usual Obj-C and C constructs ("this", "self", "super").

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you import your main app delegate header file into the view where you need to call it.
2. Use this to call it:

nameOfYourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (_nameOfYourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//than you can use appDelegate for whatever you want (ie. appDelegate.somView.someProperty )

Answer (score 0):

Ah I'm an idiot. I forgot to import a class header for a member class (i.e. I forgot to import ClassB when I tried to access [ClassA.ClassB methodB]). Of course XCode only provided an unrecognized selector runtime error rather than a missing declaration compiler error, making debugging slightly harder than it should have been. Thanks for the catch!